# How do I use SharpDevelop's PackageManagement.Cmdlets in powershell

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, powershell, sharpdevelop

I'm trying to use the PackageManagement cmdlets that come with SharpDevelop 5.1, but i'm running into a problem.

This is what i've tried

```
import-module ".\PackageManagement.Cmdlets.dll"

$solution = "C:\Git\TestProject\TestProject.sln"

$project = Get-Project TestProject $solution
```

This results in a TypeInitializationException

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageManagementServices' threw an exception.
---> ICSharpCode.Core.ServiceNotFoundException: Required service not found: 
ICSharpCode.Core.IPropertyService
```

I have also tried loading the dll in through reflection:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(".\PackageManagement.Cmdlets.dll") | Out-Null

$test = New-Object ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetProjectCmdlet
```

Which resulted in the same exception.

Looking at fusion logs, looks like the following libraries are loaded:

```
PackageManagement

NuGet.Core

ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop

ICSharpCode.Core
```

It doesn't look like the Cmdlets themselves are being loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the PackageManagement.Cmdlets.dll on its own from the PowerShell command line. It depends on parts of SharpDevelop that need to be initialized before being used.

A long time ago I created a version of [SharpDevelop 4 and the NuGet PowerShell cmdlets](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx) that you could use from the command line with PowerShell. This work was never ported to work with SharpDevelop 5.

Comment: Now I understand why it would not work when i have tried everything I could. Thank you for answering Matt! Is it easy to port the solution to the latest version of SharpDevelop?